# "unknown error" when running local Python Beam pipeline with Apache Spark and uber jar

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-beam

I'm trying to run the Python `wordcount` example using Apache Spark on my local machine (Ubuntu 22.04.2).

The command that I'm using to run the example: (see below for how I started the Spark server)

```bash
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --input=input.txt --output=output.txt \
  --runner=SparkRunner \
  --spark_submit_uber_jar \
  --spark_master_url=spark://myhostname:7077 \
  --spark_rest_url=http://myhostname:6066 \
  --environment_type=LOOPBACK
```

This fails and prints:

```
...
INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.portable_runner:Job state changed to STOPPED
INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.portable_runner:Job state changed to RUNNING
INFO:apache_beam.runners.portability.portable_runner:Job state changed to FAILED
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/jack/tmp/beam/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py", line 111, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/jack/tmp/beam/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/examples/wordcount.py", line 87, in run
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
  File "/home/jack/tmp/beam/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 601, in __exit__
    self.result.wait_until_finish()
  File "/home/jack/tmp/beam/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/portable_runner.py", line 614, in wait_until_finish
    raise self._runtime_exception
RuntimeError: Pipeline job-0d951de3-5b09-471e-b26d-a77ab56ebeb3 failed in state FAILED: unknown error
```

Master logs:

```
23/07/07 11:33:34 INFO Master: Driver submitted org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper
23/07/07 11:33:34 INFO Master: Launching driver driver-20230707113334-0006 on worker worker-20230706173048-10.90.184.126-45985
23/07/07 11:33:36 INFO Master: Removing driver: driver-20230707113334-0006
```

Worker logs:

```
23/07/07 11:33:34 INFO Worker: Asked to launch driver driver-20230707113334-0006
23/07/07 11:33:34 INFO DriverRunner: Copying user jar file:/tmp/tmp4ak6rq0w.jar to /home/jack/opt/spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3/work/driver-20230707113334-0006/tmp4ak6rq0w.jar
23/07/07 11:33:34 INFO Utils: Copying /tmp/tmp4ak6rq0w.jar to /home/jack/opt/spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3/work/driver-20230707113334-0006/tmp4ak6rq0w.jar
23/07/07 11:33:34 INFO DriverRunner: Launch Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java" "-cp" "/home/jack/opt/spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3/conf/:/home/jack/opt/spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3/jars/*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.app.name=job" "-Dspark.jars=file:/tmp/tmp4ak6rq0w.jar" "-Dspark.master=spark://myhostname:7077" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@10.90.184.126:45985" "/home/jack/opt/spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3/work/driver-20230707113334-0006/tmp4ak6rq0w.jar" "org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkPipelineRunner"
23/07/07 11:33:36 WARN Worker: Driver driver-20230707113334-0006 exited with failure
```

However, the example works if I instead use `--runner=DirectRunner`.
(The actual problem for which I want to use Beam is too large to fit in memory, so I can't use `DirectRunner`.)

I can't determine from these logs what is going wrong or where to look next.
Can someone please help?

---

My setup:

I've unzipped `spark-3.4.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz` and added `${SPARK_HOME}/bin` dir to `$PATH`/.
My `${SPARK_HOME}/conf/spark-defaults.conf` file contains:

```
spark.master.rest.enabled true
```

I started the server using:

```bash
${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-master.sh
${SPARK_HOME}/sbin/start-worker.sh spark://myhostname:7077
```

I've installed `apache-beam==2.48.0` in a virtual environment running Python 3.10.6.

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.19" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.19+7-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```